# How do I build vintage-1999 software to run on a current Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, apt-get, dpkg

I need to build some old software from source that was written for Linux 2.0 and g++ 2.8 and run it on Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox on macOS. I'm an experienced programmer in other environments, but don't know anything about building software on Linux.

I got Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on macOS and tried building the old software as is, but it fails because the compilers and Linux environment are too different from what was current in 1999. So I tried to install the environment I'm guessing the sources need, and quickly got out of my depth. It looks like the old versions of the compiler that I'm trying to install get deleted and replaced by newer versions. Let me emphasize that I really don't know what I'm doing. This is what happens:

```
$ ls *.deb
binutils_2.9.1-0.2.deb  cpp_2.7.2.3-7.deb  g++272_2.7.2.3-7.deb  gcc_2.7.2.3-7.deb  libc-4.6.27-6.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i g++272_2.7.2.3-7.deb libc-4.6.27-6.deb cpp_2.7.2.3-7.deb gcc_2.7.2.3-7.deb binutils_2.9.1-0.2.deb 
(Reading database ... 160293 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack g++272_2.7.2.3-7.deb ...
Unpacking g++272:i386 (2.7.2.3-7) over (2.7.2.3-7) ...
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 5 package 'libc':
 obsolete 'Revision' or 'Package-Revision' field used
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 10 package 'libc':
 missing architecture
dpkg: error processing archive libc-4.6.27-6.deb (--install):
 package architecture () does not match system (amd64)
Preparing to unpack cpp_2.7.2.3-7.deb ...
Unpacking cpp:i386 (2.7.2.3-7) over (2.7.2.3-7) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc_2.7.2.3-7.deb ...
Unpacking gcc:i386 (2.7.2.3-7) over (2.7.2.3-7) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading binutils from 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2 to 2.9.1-0.2
Preparing to unpack binutils_2.9.1-0.2.deb ...
Unpacking binutils:i386 (2.9.1-0.2) over (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++272:i386:
 g++272:i386 depends on libc6.

dpkg: error processing package g++272:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cpp:i386:
 cpp:i386 depends on libc6.

dpkg: error processing package cpp:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc:i386:
 gcc:i386 depends on libc6.
 gcc:i386 depends on cpp (>= 2.7.2.3-1); however:
  Package cpp:i386 is not configured yet.
 gcc:i386 depends on cpp (<< 2.7.2.4); however:
  Package cpp:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of binutils:i386:
 binutils:i386 depends on libc6.
 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2) breaks binutils (<< 2.29-6) and is installed.
  Version of binutils:i386 to be configured is 2.9.1-0.2.
 libc6-dev:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1) breaks binutils (<< 2.26) and is installed.
  Version of binutils:i386 to be configured is 2.9.1-0.2.
 binutils-common:amd64 (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2) breaks binutils (<< 2.29.1-3.1~) and is installed.
  Version of binutils:i386 to be configured is 2.9.1-0.2.
 libbinutils:amd64 (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2) breaks binutils (<< 2.29-6) and is installed.
  Version of binutils:i386 to be configured is 2.9.1-0.2.

dpkg: error processing package binutils:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-4.6.27-6.deb
 g++272:i386
 cpp:i386
 gcc:i386
 binutils:i386

$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for theuser: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  binutils:i386 cpp:i386 g++272:i386 gcc:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 4 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,396 B/31.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,649 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2 [3,396 B]
Fetched 3,396 B in 0s (17.4 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 160353 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing g++272:i386 (2.7.2.3-7) ...
Removing gcc:i386 (2.7.2.3-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binutils.
(Reading database ... 160302 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../binutils_2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2) over (2.9.1-0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp.
Preparing to unpack .../cpp_4%3a7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) over (2.7.2.3-7) ...
Setting up cpp (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up binutils (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2) ...

$
```

Comment: Packages generally don't work well outside the specific distro version they were built for. If the required C++ fixes aren't feasible, I would consider downloading an entire ancient distro such as Debian 3.0 or RedHat (non-Enterprise) 7.0. They should run fine in an emulator (or even chroot), and depending which libraries it depends on, the resulting binaries can probably be convinced to run on a modern distro.

Comment: Why is it failing to build? That's probably easier to fix than trying to install 20 year old packages.

Comment: Do you have a link to the software you can share? If so, please provide it. If not, you should probably provide more details about it.

Comment: The software I want to build is the Murphi model checker, from:
  http://www.cs.utah.edu/formal_verification/FMSD-submission/Murphi3.1.tar.gz

Comment: @jww I installed g++ then tried to build Murphi, which failed like this:
> $ make
> make -C ./src
> make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/Murphi3.1/src'
> g++ -c -O3 -Wno-write-strings -Wno-deprecated  error.C
> error.C:58:10: fatal error: stream.h: No such file or directory
>  #include <stream.h>
>           ^~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> Makefile:99: recipe for target 'error.o' failed
> make[1]: *** [error.o] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/Murphi3.1/src'
> Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Dangit. I don't seem to be able to format the code in a comment no matter what I do. I've tried five different ways and none of them work. The best I can do is tell you that I intended to start a new line every time "> " appears in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I build vintage-1999 software to run on a current Ubuntu?

There is mostly nothing special. You may need to fix some problems in the `configure.ac` script and then `auto-reconf`. Then, fix the problems you encounter during compile.

---

> ```
> $ sudo dpkg -i g++272_2.7.2.3-7.deb libc-4.6.27-6.deb cpp_2.7.2.3-7.deb gcc_2.7.2.3-7.deb binutils_2.9.1-0.2.deb 
> (Reading database ... 160293 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack g++272_2.7.2.3-7.deb ...
> Unpacking g++272:i386 (2.7.2.3-7) over (2.7.2.3-7) ...
> ...
> ```

Yeah, so don't do this. The package should work on modern Ubuntu just like it worked on ancient Ubuntu.

Just fix the problems in `configure.ac` and then `auto-reconf`. Then, fix the problems you encounter during compile.

---

> I got Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on macOS and tried building the old software as is, but it fails because the compilers and Linux environment are too different from what was current in 1999.

Yes, stay on this path if possible. Well written, portable code is usually easy to port to a new platform, even if it decades old. Even not-so-well-written code should be easier to port than trying run ancient toolchains on a new machine.

We would need to see some configure and compile errors to say more.

---

After thinking about it a bit, this is probably the path I would take. Binutils 2.9.1 was released 01-May-1998. The best you can do for Ubuntu is setup a Ubuntu 4 machine from circa 2004.

1. Ubuntu 18: `./configure`
2. Ubuntu 4: Fix configure errors
3. Ubuntu 4: `make distclean && make dist` for new tarball
4. `scp` new tarball from Ubuntu 4 to Ubuntu 18
5. Lather, rinse, repeat

The benefit of this is, you can avoid most of the Autotools problems by creating an updated tarball on Ubuntu 4 using vintage `autoconf` and `automake`. `configure` should (will eventually?) run on Ubuntu 18 without problems.

Eventually, on Ubuntu 18, your will be able to `autoupdate` to convert the package to a modern Autotools before `configure`.

---

If you are flexible on your version of Ubuntu, then use something like [Ubuntu 4](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/). You can do the same with [Fedora 1](https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/). They install in a modern VM. They will have ancient versions of Glibc and Binutils already installed.

I do this sort of thing all the time at [Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). The build scripts installs modern cURL, Git, Wget (and friends) on the ancient distros like Fedora 1 and Ubuntu 4 (and anything in between).

With modern tools I can regression test libraries like Crypto++ and OpenSSL to ensure they still build with ancient compilers, assemblers and linkers. Crypto++ and OpenSSL are old school libraries. They have been around since the mid-1990s. No bleeding edge required, they rarely give up backwards compatibility.

---

> that was written for Linux 2.0 and g++ 2.8

Linux 2.0 and GCC 2.8 is *really* going back in time. I *think* the closest you are going to be able to do without much pain is Linux 2.4 and GCC 3.3. Or you need to use an ancient [Debian (Hamm) release](https://www.debian.org/releases/) with Linux 2.0.

If you stay the course with Ubuntu, I believe you can download and build [GCC 2.95 from source](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html). GCC 2.8 is listed, but there are no download links for it. I'm not sure where you can find it.

Here are the specs for the distros on my VMs:

***Fedora 1***:

```
$ uname -a
Linux fedora1.home.pvt. 2.4.22-1.2199.nptl #1 Wed Aug 4 12:21:48 EDT 2004 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.3.2 20031022 (Red Hat Linux 3.3.2-1)
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ld --version
GNU ld version 2.14.90.0.6 20030820
Copyright 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.  This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

***Ubuntu 4***:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu4.home.pvt 2.6.8.1-3-386 #1 Tue Oct 12 12:41:57 BST 2004 i686 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.3.4 (Debian 1:3.3.4-9ubuntu5)
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ld --version
GNU ld version 2.14.90.0.7 20031029 Debian GNU/Linux
Copyright 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.  This program has absolutely no warranty.
```